# Using grep from python console

Tags: python, grep, pipe, ipython

Using python how can I make this happen?

```
python_shell$>  print myPhone.print_call_log()  |  grep 555
```

The only thing close that I've seen is using "ipython console", assigning output to a variable, and then using a .grep() function on that variable.  This is not really what I'm after.  I want pipes and grepping on anything in the output (including errors/info).

Comment: It's a mistake to use the Python interactive console as a long-term shell environment. Use it for testing Python statements; attempting to use it as a general purpose shell is inviting an endless series of frustrations like this.

Comment: Use `re` to do pattern match in python or write the log to a temp file   to use `grep`.

Comment: ipython has way to handle grepping output from a shell/system command.  [Example post](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.9.1/html/interactive/shell.html#string-lists) from ipython's documentation.  I'm hoping someone has bent this ability to be easier to leverage, and not limited to the contents of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's interactive REPL doesn't have `grep`, nor process pipelines, since it's not a Unix shell. You need to work with Python objects.

So, assuming the return value of `myPhone.print_call_log` is a sequence:

```python
call_log_entries = myPhone.print_call_log()
entries_containing_555 = [
        entry for entry in call_log_entries
        if "555" in entry]
```

Comment: I think 'myPhone.print_call_log()' is a `'\n'` separated string and can use `split('\n')` to convert it to a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this.

```
import subprocess
results = subprocess.check_output('cat /path/to/call_log.txt | grep 555', shell=True)
print(results)
```

Or:

```
import subprocess
string = myPhone.print_call_log().replace("\'","\\'")
results = subprocess.check_output('echo \''+string+'\' | grep 555', shell=True)
print(results)
```

It is hard to tell without knowing what the return type of myPhone.print_call_log(). Is it a generator, or does it return a list? Or a string?

Related Questions:

- [piping in shell via Python subprocess module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405515/piping-in-shell-via-python-subprocess-module)
- [Assign output of os.system to a variable and prevent it from being displayed on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on)

Docs:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

## Edit:

Based on comment by glglgl

Something like this might be more appropriate as written by glglgl:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10363929/2026508

Comment: Rather than `results = subprocess.check_output('echo \''+myPhone.print_call_log()+'\' | grep 555', shell=True)`, a combination of `stdin=stubprocess.PIPE` and `.communicate()` would be more appropriate... but then, you can omit the subprocess altogether and perform the search on your own.

Comment: BTW, what do you do if there are any `'` in your `print_call_log()` output? If you replace them by `'\''`, you should be fine. But "elegant" is not quite the right word for this...