# How do I use grep on Windows while using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, grep

I need to use the grep command to search for a pattern in a text file. But I'm on Windows so how do I do that? Oh and I have to use python.

My teacher said we have to input something like

grep "Hello" file.txt

in **Python's shell**.

But base on what I found in the internet, that should be inputted in Linux's terminal. I asked our teacher about it but he said I should just look for it on YouTube :(

I really don't have any idea how to do this and where to start. Please help me!

EDIT: I used re.search to do the same thing before but my teacher won't accept it. I really have to use grep!

If anyone has any idea how that is possible please tell me

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236)

Comment: [findstr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr) and [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7) are comparable commands on Windows

Comment: What does this have to do with Python? There's no built-in `grep` in Windows, [the closest alternative is `findstr`](https://superuser.com/questions/300815/grep-equivalent-for-windows-7).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm sorry. But my question is this "How do I use grep on Windows while using Python?" I want to know if this is really possible.

Comment: @ForceBru RIGHT?! But my teacher insists to use python for it. That's why I was wondering if anyone has an idea how do I do that.

Comment: @Abdul Yea, but my teacher wants grep :(

Comment: There is a Windows version of `grep`, so the answer is "yes, you may if you install all these apps".

Comment: @Rose In that case, ForceBru's link has an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/301075) that shares 2 options on getting `grep` on Windows

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm okay with installing apps.. but what app will make it possible for me to input/use grep in python's shell?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23798617/using-grep-from-python-console

Comment: For future reference, see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), point #3: 'Questions asking for homework help'

Comment: @Lucan Hi! Sorry I thought I already followed what it said. I'll be clearer next time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `os` module.

```
import os

os.sytem("grep -w \"Hello\" file.txt")

# Note:
# Command has to be a string.
# Command should have escape characters, like \".
```

You can install grep for Windows from **[this site](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm)**.

Comment: Hi!! I did what you said. But when I tried to print it, it only outputs "1". Why is this?

Comment: It's just and example. You should read a manual for grep and find switches that you have to use. I don't know what pattern are you looking for, so I can't help you right now.